# OpenGL load shader file failed

Tags: opengl

Error Message

GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated.  has not been linked, or is not a program object.
GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated.  object is not successfully linked, or is not a program object.

I think that it cannot find the glsl file, what should I do?

shader.vs.glsl

```
    #version 430 core 

void main(void) 
{ 
const vec4 vertices[6] = vec4[6](vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0),
vec4(0.5,-0.5,0.0,1.0),
vec4(-0.5,-0.5,0.0,1.0),
vec4(0.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0),
vec4(0.5,0.5,0.0,1.0),
vec4(-0.5,0.5,0.0,1.0)
);
gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID]; 
}
```

shader.fs.glsl

```
    #version 430 core 

out vec4 color; 

void main(void) 
{ 
 color = vec4(0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
}
```

compile_shaders()

```
GLuint compile_shaders()
{ 
    GLuint vs;
    GLuint fs;
    GLuint program;
    vs=sb6::shader::load("media\shaders\dispmap\dispmap.vs.glsl",GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  fs=sb6::shader::load("media\shaders\dispmap\dispmap.fs.glsl",GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

// Create program, attach shaders to it, and link it
program = glCreateProgram();

glAttachShader(program, vs);
glAttachShader(program, fs);

glLinkProgram(program);


return program;
}
```

my_application class

```
class my_application : public sb6::application
{
public:
void startup()
{
    rendering_program =compile_shaders();
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);
}
void shutdown()
{ 
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    glDeleteProgram(rendering_program);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
}
private:
GLuint rendering_program;
GLuint vertex_array_object;

void render(double currentTime)
{
    const GLfloat color[] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };

    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

    // Use the program object we created earlier for rendering

    glUseProgram(rendering_program);

    // Draw one point
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
};
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you escape backslashes in your path, and check return values of shader load?

Comment: I excape backslashes in my path. Still not working.

if(!vs || !fs){return NULL;}  this work, it always return NULL

Comment: Then clearly shader isn't loaded. I have no ideas what `sb6::shader` is. Go further into load function.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9412194
This is the inside of she shader.I don't know what should I do...

Comment: Is there another way to load glsl file?

Comment: OK,I got it. I add a file to project directly  and I can load it.

Comment: http://jack120707.blogspot.tw/2014/07/opengl-glsl.html